# How to calculate Date days difference, and not by seconds?

Tags: java, date

For example i have two dates:

```
2018-11-30 18:00:00
2018-12-01 00:00:00
```

How you can see, that less then 24 hours difference, but I need to recognize that a one day of differnce, and i can't just subtract, cause of month change. 
In output i need to return int count of days.

In c# it will be just:

```
(EndDate - StartDate).TotalDays
```

What Java code will be similar?

I searched somewhere before I asked, but that didn’t solve the problem. Here’s my attempt after searching:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
LocalDateTime d1 = LocalDateTime.parse("2018-11-30 18:00:00", dtf);
LocalDateTime d2 = LocalDateTime.parse("2018-12-01 00:00:00", dtf);
long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(d1, d2);
System.out.println("Days: " + days); // Days: 0
```

I wish to get 1 day of difference.

Comment: `ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(startDateTime.toLocalDate(), endDateTime.toLocalDate())`. If you are serious about getting an `int`, not a `long`, pass through `Math.toIntExact()`.

Comment: In case I didn’t find the best original questions and answers for you, please just continue searching, they are out there for sure.

Comment: Thanks for answer, i search somewhere before ask, but problem doesn't solved:

```
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        LocalDateTime d1 = LocalDateTime.parse("2018-11-30 18:00:00", dtf);
        LocalDateTime d2 = LocalDateTime.parse("2018-12-01 00:00:00", dtf);
        
        long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(d1, d2);
        
        System.out.println("Days: " + days); // Days: 0
```

I wish to get 1 day of difference.

Comment: Really nice attempt, and really close. Just convert to `LocalDate` as in my first comment: `ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(d1.toLocalDate(), d2.toLocalDate())`. This will give 1 day (I have tried it). PS I upvoted your question after you have now provided MCVE with desired and observed result.

Comment: Oh *facepalm* shame on me. Thank you, LocalDates works as expected.